# Prove that a function satisfying $|f(x)| \le|x|$ for all $x$ is continuous at $0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, continuity

> **Def$^n$**: A function $f$ is *continuous at a* if $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = f(a)$.

We have also defined that the sum and product of two continuous functions is continuous because of rules of computation for limits, as is the quotient provided the denominator is not 0.

The question is as follows and is from Spivak Ch6, 3(a):

> Suppose that $f$ is a function satisfying $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ for all $x$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $0$. (Notice that $f(0)$ must equal $0$.)

I have found a solution to this problem by manipulating the inequality. We can show that:

$0 \leq |f(x)| \leq |x|$, and furthermore it follows that $0 \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} |x|$ = 0. Hence, it is true that $0 \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) \leq 0$ only if the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$.

Therefore, $f(0) = 0$.

Is this sufficient as a proof? How can I make this proof more concrete and how would I rigorously prove this? Hints are appreciated.

Comment: Try to use the definition of continuity involving $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: "Notice that f(0) must equal 0." should read "Notice that poor f(0) cannot exist as its absolute value should be less than $0$"

Comment: No function can satisfy $|f(x)|\lt|x|$ for *all* $x$, since $|f(0)|$ cannot be *less* than $0$. So technically speaking, what you are trying to prove is *vacuously* true

Comment: Unfortunately I included a typo, it should read |f(x)| $\leq$ |x|.

Comment: No, what you wrote is not sufficient. That $f(0)=0$ has nothing to do with limits.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo How so? How do I fix this proof so that f(0) = 0 makes sense? Do I have to add $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$ and thus f(a) = f(0) = 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon\gt0$. Choose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
0\lt|x-0|\lt\delta\implies|f(x)-0|&\le|x-0|\\
&\lt\delta\\
&=\epsilon\\
\end{align}
Hence $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(0)$ by definition.

Comment: We can choose $\delta$ = $\epsilon$ because we have power over what $\delta$ we choose, correct? Consequently, we use our defined $\delta$ in the definition of continuity as above? Does it follow that f(0) = 0 because a = 0 in this definition?

Comment: This is the standard layout of a proof that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. $f(0)=0$ because $|f(x)|\le|0|\implies f(0)=0$.